# Is there a programmatic way to know a node.js app is running in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Is there some variable or function I can call to know if a node.js application is running inside Heroku? Something like:

```
if (process.heroku)
  console.log("I'm in Heroku!");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this without setting custom environment variables. You can do it like this:

```
if (process.env._ && process.env._.indexOf("heroku") !== -1)
   console.log("I'm in Heroku!");
```

This is possible because on a Heroku dyno the `_` environment variable is set to `/app/.heroku/node/bin/node`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (not sure how it has 7 upvotes and accepted). `indexOf` will return 0 as a valid result which would evaluate to false. It returns -1 for no results which would evaluate to true. Neither of these are correct. To fix, change to `(process.env._.indexOf("heroku") !== -1)`

Comment: It probably got the upvotes because it steered people in the right direction. It took a while but I've corrected my answer with your fix @Joel.

Answer (score 13):

You use for that usual environment variables.
Just set some variable on your heroku instance and check this:

`process.env.HEROKU`

On the heroku cli you would do:
`heroku config:set HEROKU=true`

You can also set it on the web interface, see heroku docs for more:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I think this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

On this specific case I've used `if test -d /app; then npm run build; fi` which can be used also inside npm-scripts.