# Check if API is running within Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

How do I check within my Node / Express app if it is running within Heroku?

My understanding is that .env files don't work in Heroku. So this line will crash the app in Heroku. So, I want to prevent running this within a Heroku environment.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#be-environmentally-aware

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a programmatic way to know a node.js app is running in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472113/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-know-a-node-js-app-is-running-in-heroku)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it is to create an environment variable called `IS_HEROKU`. On Heroku that's done in the app's dashboard, in the Settings tab, under *Config Variables*. Add `IS_HEROKU: true`. You can also use the CLI:

```
heroku config:set IS_HEROKU=true
```

It's described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

You will now have access to it with `process.env.IS_HEROKU`. The value is a string.

I feel is simpler to use environment variables this way compared to using dotenv. If it was my project I would specify all the environment variables this way.